# Why User object in auth0/nextjs useUser hook is missing properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, auth0

User object in `auth0/nextjs` `useUser` hook is missing properties

I can't seem to get the while user object from the useUser hook in `auth0/nextjs`:

```js
{
  "nickname": "example",
  "name": "example@yahoo.com",
  "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/ca48de58bbf91d5963aa…&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Fal.png",
  "updated_at": "2022-05-19T13:13:29.487Z",
  "sub": "auth0|628639882896f400694b6e72"
}
```

As you can see there are many properties missing such as email etc..
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your [scopes](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/apis/scopes/sample-use-cases-scopes-and-claims).

*Example of usage*, in your `[...auth0].js` file, than in `/api/auth/me` you will see needed info

```
import { handleAuth, handleLogin, handleProfile } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';


export default handleAuth({
  async login(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleLogin(req, res, {
        returnTo: '/api/auth/me',
        authorizationParams: {
          response_type: 'code',
          scope: 'openid profile email',
        }
      });

    } catch (error) {
      res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
    }
    
  }
});
```